# Blog home page has canonical link that is incorrect. Do not see where to change this

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, next-post-link, rel-canonical

As part of our website we have a wordpress blog in a subdirectory. I scanned our main site for broken links. The scan included the wordpress blog in the subdirectory. Some "broken links" showed up that have never been present before. The problem is that the "otherblog" has nothing whatsoever to do with our website--it is a separate property. We don't know how the value for the "otherblog" is getting in.

The html looks like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.otherblog.com/blog/">
<link rel="next" href="https://www.otherblog.com/blog/page/2/">
```

In addition to the canonical link, there is also a bogus "next" link. Where do these bogus settings come from?

Searching on "wordpress canonical link is wrong" and similar searches lead to pages that give instructions similar to the following generic steps:

1. Go to the page where the problem occurs.
2. In the Yoast advanced section, adjust the entry for "canonical".

An example of such instructions are at https://yoast.com/help/canonical-urls-in-wordpress-seo/.

However this does not help for one of the following reasons:

1. The page in question is the site home page, and there is no way to "go to that page" in the admin section.
2. For pages not on the blog home page, the Yoast canonical field is empty, and does not have the bogus value in it.

So where is the bogus value coming from, and how does one correct it?

Again, we have not had this issue previously over a period of many years. So it seems odd to start overriding entries on certain pages. And such an override would be to the same page anyways, which is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install "Yoast Test Helper" Plugin
2. Navigate to Tools -> Yoast Test
3. Under Yoast SEO, Click the "Reset Indexables tables & migrations"

Comment: We have already discovered that the described steps will fix the problem. For a detailed explanation, see https://wordpress.org/support/topic/canonical-and-next-links-point-to-a-different-website-fix-by-reset-indexable/#new-topic-0

Comment: this bug literally removed our site from google search index. thanks for this priceless answer!